# How install any package in python 2.7 when you have 3 installed with anaconda?

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, pycharm

My mac came with default python 2.7 and i installed python 3 now i am using pycharm and anaconda setup. Problem is when i try to install "keras" or any other package in python 2.7 so i change pycharm interpreter to --> python 2.7 but when i install keras from terminal by typing "pip install keras" and it install successfully but when i try to import keras from python 2.7 it says no module name keras and so i think it install in python 3. My question is how can i install packages in python 2.7 ?

Comment: `/path/to/python27 -m pip install keras` or you could try `pip2 install keras`

Answer (score 3):

As you have two different versions of python, you will also have two versions of pip.

```
where pip
```

should return the locations of the different versions of pip. Type the full path to the version of pip that you want instead of just "pip":

```
C:\users\jbloggs...\pip.exe install keras
```

Answer (score 1):

You can specify python version when installing

```
pip2 install any-package
```

Answer (score 0):

Install using

```
sudo python -m pip install keras
```

this way the package will be installed with the chosen `python` interpreter's pip